# inline date picker implementation

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uidatepicker

i am developing an application which is retrieve some data from a web service and show them in a table view.i want to filter the data on the date.so i have tried to implement a in line date picker. so i have successfully done an exercise by help of [this](http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/).

so i have a question : as i know, all the rows are filled to the table view via cellForRowAtIndexPath method. can i do such a thing like , when i select a date from the inline date picker, it should be load the cells by calling the web service according to the date..

simply , first of all all the cells should be empty. when we touch the top most cell , in line date picker is showed. after we select the date, then the cells should be loaded.. can i do that ? if it is ,can some one give me some idea how to do that?  please guide me with some links , code samples ideas.. anything....

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this take picker in Xib and connect it properly, And set IBAction as  ValueChanged

after that call this method while changing the date

```
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged: (id)sender {
    NSDate *selectedDate = [sender date];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedDate);
    //do something with selectedDate
}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to load the table view with different layout after i select the date ?

Comment: Yes you can relaod the tableview or particuler cell or particuler section.

Comment: thank you ... can you give me some tutorial links regarding that :)